# Using cordova google maps plugin with angular /ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, cordova, ionic-framework

Do someone knows how to use "plugin.google.maps" inside controllers while using ionic framework?

I need to handle clicks on markers (plugin.google.maps.event.MARKER_CLICK), and pop some information (outside the map), so I can't stay inside the "run" method.

"controllers.js" :

```
 .controller('GetShopsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    var div = document.getElementById("map_canvas");
    var map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap();      
})
```

.

```
ReferenceError: plugin is not defined
```

Thanks!

PS : I also asked this question here : http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/using-google-maps-cordova-plugin/4456/83

Comment: I don't succeed in editing my post to say "Hi!" !

Answer (score 0):

This should do it: Inside the div set `map.setClickable( false )`.

After closing set `map.setClickable( true )`.

Also, make sure to listen to the click events correctly.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

you get this error when you dont have google play service installed in Android amulator or you are running your app in browser, plugin is native and will only work on a device...